# How can I inject HttpServletRequest attributes (set in interceptor) in my controller?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to add an attribute to all my requests before they reach the controller.

What I am using :

```
@Component
public class SessionValidatorInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    .... some code ....
    request.setAttribute("validRequest","true");
    .... more code ...
    return true;
}
```

Now to get this attribute in my rest controller I am doing :

```
public ResponseEntity<?> someMethod(HttpServletRequest request){
    request.getAttribute("validSession");
    ...
```

My question is can I do this more elegantly like @RequestParam("validSession")  or @PathVariable or something else?
Can Spring do this for me ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: How about `@RequestAttribute` (available as of Spring 4.3).

Comment: Wow. How stupid am I?
thanks @M.Deinum . Please post as answer so I can accept. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring 4.3 the `@RequestAttribute` annotation was added just for this.

```
public void yourMethod(@RequestAttribute("validRequest") boolean valid)
```

something like that should do the trick.

If you are on an earlier version of Spring you can implement your own [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to do the same.

Comment: thanks. I am using current spring version so that worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `@RequestAttribute`
Like this

```
public ResponseEntity<?> someMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
@RequestAttribute("validSession") String xyz){
}
```

Since, Mr. Denim didn't post answer, i thought why not me. ^_^